# Are there object creation expressions in Java, similar to the ones in C#?

Tags: c#, java, object, constructor

In C#, I can create an instance of every custom class that I write, and pass values for its members, like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int number;
    public string text;
}

var newInstance = new MyClass { number = 1, text = "some text" };
```

This way of creating objects is called [object creation expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691345%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Is there a way I can do the same in Java? I want to pass values for arbitrary public members of a class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there's nothing directly similar. The closest you can come in Java (without writing a builder class etc) is to use an anonymous inner class and initializer block, which is horrible but works:

```
MyClass foo = new MyClass()
{{
    number = 1;
    text = "some text";
}};
```

Note the double braces... one to indicate "this is the contents of the anonymous inner class" and one to indicate the initializer block. I *wouldn't* recommend this style, personally.

Comment: Plus one for horrible, defines another class, doesn't work for final classes or fields. But I do use this in test code where expressiveness can be more important.

Comment: agree with Jon, don't use that!

Comment: @irreuptable: I never said it was bad for performance. It's just nasty to create a new class when you don't need any real behavioural tweaks, just different initialization.

Answer (score 0):

No. But I don't find the following code too verbose

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.number = 1;
obj.text = "some text";
```

Or the good old constructor calling too confusing

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(1, "some text");
```

Some may suggest method chaining:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass().number(1).text("some text");

class MyClass
    int number
    public MyClass number(int number){ this.number=number; return this; }
```

which requires an extra method per field. It's boiler plate code, an IDE may help here.

Then there's the builder pattern, which is even more work for the API author.

Comment: The first code snippet us much more verbose than the C# equivalent. Also, you cannot pass it directly as a parameter in a method, you have to create an instance and assign it to a variable. The constructor way has one big disadvantage - you have to manually implement the constructor in each class you want to use this way. Same thing for the method chaining, although it is even more effort.